# Different baseline data for sites

Tags: mixed-model, mixed-type-data

I have the data with 2 treatments and 1 site (see the image). I am trying to run a mixed model with the code below.

```r
model <- lmer(Yield ~ Treatment + Variety + (1 | site), 
              data = yieldn, REML = FALSE)
```

However, I have one confusion. If you look at the data the "Treatment" (amount of nitrogen added/present) has three levels but the first level at each site is different. So when the first level of treatment at sites is different but followed by similar second and third level. How do you consider for this variation in the model?

There are three levels of treatments of Nitrogen fertilizer, to check the effects of fertilizer on yield. Treatment level 2 and 3 is to apply exactly same amount of nitrogen to all plots. However treatment level 1 is the amount of nitrogen already present in the soil. but since these sites are different from each other, amount of N present is different. Aim is to check if Nitrogen applied to these sites can gradually increase yield.

[image]

Comment: What’s the aim of the analysis?

Comment: There are three treatments of Nitrogen fertilizer, to check the effects of fertilizer on yield. Treatment 2 and 3 is to apply exactly same amount of nitrogen to all plots. However treatment level 1 is the amount of nitrogen already present in the soil. but since these sites are different from each other, amount of N present is different. Aim is to check if Nitrogen applied to these sites can gradually increase yield.

Answer (score 2):

This model,

```r
model <- lmer(Yield ~ Treatment + Variety + (1 | site), 
              data = yieldn, REML = FALSE)
```

Incorporates a random intercept for each site, which accounts for the inherent variability between sites.

This model,

```r
model <- lmer(Yield ~ Treatment + Variety + (1 + Treatment | site), 
              data = yieldn, REML = FALSE)
```

in addition to a random intercept for each site, also contains a random slope for the treatment within each site. This implies that the impact of the treatment on yield varies from site to site.